# Rails pass input in link_to

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

How can I pass html element input value in link_to path?

```
%input#answer{type: "text", required: true}
%p
= link_to "Send", game_answer_path(@game),  class: 'btn btn-default', remote: true
```

I can get my input value as `document.getElementById("answer").value`, but how can I pass it in `game_answer_path(@game, HERE )`?

Comment: Maybe what you need to do can be achieved in other way, but you can't mix server side with client side code. Can you explain?

Comment: answer is just an id of simple input (client) and I want pass it to server by pass value as param

Comment: If what you are doing is creating an answer you should be using a form to send a POST request instead of GET.

Answer (score 1):

How do you get value in the `answer` field, if you get it from the backend then you can add to the link time when your view is being rendered so you can do something like,

```
= link_to "Send", game_answer_path(@game, :answer => @answer),  class: 'btn btn-default', remote: true
```

if that value is being generated by a user action like user selecting or entering an answer then you need to use to dynamically append it to the value of the anchor (href) tag, using javascript you can do something like

```
var link = document.getElementById("link").value
document.getElementById("link").href = value + '/' +  document.getElementById("answer").value
```

replace `link` and `answer` with respective id from your dom, if this is not what you are after, update your question.

Comment: what is "link" here? I dont use any elements with such id. And yes, answer is id of user input element. I just need create an variable like  `document.getElementById("answer").value` and pass it like u done it above `game_answer_path(@game, :answer => @answer)`

Comment: do you send the answer by submitting a form or by clicking on a href link ?

Comment: I dont use form here, just clicking link_to.

Comment: so do you want the answer to be sent with the link, something like, http://example.com/action/answer or http://example.com/action?answer=answer_value ?

Comment: glad to be of help